# Generically Binding Values with ngModel

Tags: angular, angular-ngmodel, angular-pipe

I am just learning Angular 2 and one issue I've been unable to tackle is creating forms with ngModel without statically specifying the name of the attribute I am binding to.

I am unsure of the mechanisms for overcoming this problem (though I am sure it's common enough) or how it's referred to within the community.

My template *does* display the keys and values but it doesn't reflect the updates on save. It seems like referring to the attribute in a dynamic way causes the binding to be lost. (Is it evaluating the bound attribute before piping the data?)

Here is where I am stuck:

Template:

```
<table class="table table-responsive">
  <tr *ngFor="let prop of account | keyValues">
    <td>{{ prop.key }}</td>

    // Problem here:
    // if I have [(ngModel)]="prop.key", it only displays the keys
    // if I sub in a static attribute e.g. [(ngModel)]="account.accountName" it works
    <td><input name="{{prop.key}}"  [(ngModel)]="prop.value" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Pipe:

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'keyValues'
})
@Injectable()
export class KeysPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value, args:string[]) : any {
    let keys = [];
    for (let key in value) {
      keys.push({key: key, value: value[key]});
    }
    return keys;
  }
}
```

Component:

```
  ... boiler plate ...

  save(): void {
    this.accountsService.update(this.account)
      .then(() => this.goBack());
  }

  ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is to use Angular's [Dynamic Forms](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-form.html)

You can also leverage certain libraries like PrimeFaces' PrimeNG's editable datatable, which I highly recommend!